# save my offline plotly plot as html file locally

Tags: python, plotly

In my jupyter notebook, I made an offline interactive plot with plotly. I'm trying to save this interactive plot as a html file locally.

Below is my code. However, I cannot find my file I intended to save anywhere. Does anyone know what I did wrong?
Thanks a lot.

```
py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

y = np.random.randn(500)
data = [go.Histogram(y=y)]

py.offline.iplot(data, filename='myplot.html')
```

Comment: A similar example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567113/how-to-save-plotly-graphic-without-showing can be used to save a plot directly via `write_html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `iplot` which is the interactive plot method that plots it in the Jupyter notebook for you to see. If you want to generate the HTML file change `iplot` to `plot` and it will create it for you:

```
import plotly as py
py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

y = np.random.randn(500)
data = [go.Histogram(y=y)]

py.offline.plot(data, filename='myplot.html')
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/) the `plotly.offline.plot` are in some way deprecated from version 4 and on. See [Ran Feldesh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59457794/8849755).

Answer (score 2):

Plotly 4.x:

Use [to_html](https://plot.ly/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.to_html.html#plotly.io.to_html) or [write_html](https://plot.ly/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.write_html.html#plotly.io.write_html).

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.bar(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width')
pio.write_html(fig, file='iris.html')
```

[reference](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started-with-chart-studio/#initialization-for-offline-plotting)

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, if you are using Cufflinks or any other offline mode, you can export the html interactive graph in the following way:

```
# Original cufflinks call to plot the graph within a Jupyter Notebook:

plyo.iplot(pv.iplot(asFigure=True,kind='bar',xTitle='REF',yTitle='Defects',title='Kind of Defects',barmode='stack'))

# Export to html file

fig =pv.iplot(asFigure=True,kind='bar',xTitle='REF',yTitle='Defects',title='Kind of Defects',barmode='stack')

pio.write_html(fig, file='defects.html')
```

Comment: If possible, please reformat your question using `backticks` to denote code. Otherwise, it can be difficult for users to read.