# how to save plotly graphic without showing?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, plotly

I have a large Gantt Chart plotting by plotly in anaconda enviroment. However, as it takes 10 mins to plot, and sometime it does not come out. So I think if the figure can be saved directly as svg file than I can check later.

I tried to go through the documentation and research online, what I can see it when the figure is plotted, then you can save it. but in my case, sometime it does not come out. So is there anyway we can directly write the figure to the disk?

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

df = [dict(Task="Job-1", Start='2017-01-01', Finish='2017-02-02',      Resource='Complete'),
  dict(Task="Job-1", Start='2017-02-15', Finish='2017-03-15', Resource='Incomplete'),
  dict(Task="Job-2", Start='2017-01-17', Finish='2017-02-17', Resource='Not Started'),
  dict(Task="Job-2", Start='2017-01-17', Finish='2017-02-17', Resource='Complete'),
  dict(Task="Job-3", Start='2017-03-10', Finish='2017-03-20', Resource='Not Started'),
  dict(Task="Job-3", Start='2017-04-01', Finish='2017-04-20', Resource='Not Started'),
  dict(Task="Job-3", Start='2017-05-18', Finish='2017-06-18', Resource='Not Started'),
  dict(Task="Job-4", Start='2017-01-14', Finish='2017-03-14', Resource='Complete')]

colors = {'Not Started': 'rgb(220, 0, 0)',
      'Incomplete': (1, 0.9, 0.16),
      'Complete': 'rgb(0, 255, 100)'}

fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=colors, index_col='Resource',     show_colorbar=True,
                  group_tasks=True)
fig.show()
```

The real code is similar but far longer than this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fig.write_html()` or, if you install [Orca](https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/), you can use `fig.write_image()`

Comment: thanks it is solved by your way. But I can't vote yet